# React Native - Navigation from inner components

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, uinavigationcontroller, navigator

In a React Native application, how can I perform navigation when touching in some component not directly tied up with the main `Navigator`?

```
Main // Here I have my main NavigatorIOS
└─TabBar
  └─ListView
    └─Cell // onTap should navigate to a detail page about my cell.
```

In Xcode this is really simple to perform, even programmatically, using a `segue`.

Is there a way to access a main Navigator object to perform navigation from a independent component?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/).
Its so simple solution and easy to use.It has stack and [tab navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab) support  too.

You can define screens in the router and call it from anywhere. Basic example would go like this.

```
BasicApp.js . 

import {
  StackNavigator,
} from 'react-navigation';

const BasicApp = StackNavigator({
  Main: {screen: MainScreen},
  Profile: {screen: ProfileScreen},
});
```

where MainScreen and ProfileScreen are your components.  You can navigate simple by calling navigate in th eonPress of a button or something.

```
<Button
        title="Go to Jane's profile"
        onPress={() =>
          navigate('Profile', { name: 'Jane' })
        }
      />
```

Comment: I've tested after you said to use it but the method `navigate` could not be found. `Cell` is the last element of a whole hierarchy and it's inside a child of my navigator. The method `navigate` can really be called that deep?

Comment: u need add that screen inside Stack/Tabnavigator then use the navigate after importing it like     const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

Comment: That's my point. I'd have to chain a huge amount of props depending on my hierarchy. Your solution works if I have a shallow hierarchy, otherwise it's hard to maintain.

Comment: You could use navigator for containers and make the components dumb (something that includes callbacks and redux). So u only need to maintain the containers while the components remain dumb

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by dispatching an event that will be handled by react-navigation reducers.

Add the code below to your render method

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { this.props.goBack() }}>
```

And then user mapDispatchToProps to define a method as a prop which dispatches the navigation action.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    goBack: () => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'Navigation/BACK'
      })
    }
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent)
```

This dispatches an action to go to previous page.

If you want to navigate to any screen, you can use Navigation/NAVIGATE type.

Render code:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { this.props.goToPage('HomeScreen') }}>
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { this.props.goToPage('OtherScreen') }}>
```

Dispatch function:

```
    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
      return {
        goToPage: (page) => {
          dispatch({
            type: 'Navigation/NAVIGATE',
            routeName: page,
            params: {param1, param2}
          })
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Cell.js :

```
<Touchable onPress={this.props.onPress}/>
```

ListView.js :

```
<Cell onPress={this.props.onPress}/>
```

Tabbar.js :

```
<ListView onPress={this.props.onPress}/>
```

Main.js :

```
<TabBar onPress={this.onPressCell}/>
OnPressCell=()=> ....whatever you want
```

Comment: Completely unsustainable solution. Maybe the better option is integrate with Redux.